# Regex to get the filename with dash and forward slash of URL

Tags: regex

Im trying to make a regex for a link like this

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/locs/my-locs" />`

i want to get my-locs as regex

```
(?:[^/][\d\w\.]+)$(?:")
```

here's what I've been trying

Comment: Regex is not reliable to parse HTML. Best to inspect/manipulate the DOM directly using native methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

`(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=\")`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3F2r8o/1)

**UPDATE**

`(href=\".*?)(?<=\/)([^\/<> ]+)(?=\")`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNc7P7/3)

Comment: Amazing it straight up solve my problem. but it is giving problem with multiple line of text. Is there any specific way to fix it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gNc7P7/2
Look i just was the last texts

Comment: @AirasKhan I updated my answer, hope this pattern helps you.

Comment: and to get results you must get group 2 result

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that also makes sure it starts with either http, or https, and has several other checks for urls: `https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`

Comment: But if you are only going to be getting it from html, there should be easier ways, like searching for an href tag, and going after that.

Comment: I just want to get the final my-locs after the second last slash and preceding a quotation

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?="\s*\/>)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/7JIP73/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w-]+                   any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), '-' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```